# NamedEntityGraph ignore in Spring Data Rest

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have a Repository, whose findAll Method is marked with `@EntityGraph`. I'm printing the generated SQL to the log and I can see that it generates the right join select when used directly in Java (i.e., `myRepo.findAll();`).
But when I call this via REST, this does not happen. I either get an Exception, bc. the Lazy-Loading proxy can't be serialized, or if I add jackson-databind-hibernate5, I can see additional queries.

I've tried to generate a minimal reproduction here: https://github.com/cptwunderlich/SpringDataRestDemo

I can't see the additional queries and there is no exception, so I suspect that the Entity is already in the Cache, but it issues a select without a join.

Here an excerpt of the code (getters/setters/etc. generated with lombok, some boilerplate omitted for brevity!):

Entities:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true)
public class Bar {
  @Id @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  private String value;

  @Version
  private Long version;
}

@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "Foo.full", includeAllAttributes = true)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"name"})
public class Foo {
  @Id @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @NonNull
  private Bar bar;

  @Version
  private Long version;
}
```

Repository:

```
@RestResource
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long> {

  @EntityGraph(value = "Foo.full", type = EntityGraphType.LOAD)
  @Override
  List<Foo> findAll();
}
```

Generated query for findAll:

```
select
    foo0_.id as id1_1_0_,
    bar1_.id as id1_0_1_,
    foo0_.bar_id as bar_id4_1_0_,
    foo0_.name as name2_1_0_,
    foo0_.version as version3_1_0_,
    bar1_.value as value2_0_1_,
    bar1_.version as version3_0_1_ 
from
    foo foo0_ 
left outer join
    bar bar1_ 
        on foo0_.bar_id=bar1_.id
```

Query via REST:

```
select
    foo0_.id as id1_1_,
    foo0_.bar_id as bar_id4_1_,
    foo0_.name as name2_1_,
    foo0_.version as version3_1_ 
from
    foo foo0_ limit ?
```

Comment: As I'm posting this, I notice the "limit" clause in the second query. Is it possible that Spring Data Rest applies paging and that somehow interferes with joins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG, I just figured it out. A form of rubber ducky debugging I suppose.

As I was posting this, I noticed the "limit ?" clause in the second query. I manually added a @Query and countQuery and didn't see a change. Then it dawned on me - where did the argument for `limit` come from?

It's simply a different method:

```
  @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"bar"})
  @Override
  List<Foo> findAll();

  @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"bar"})
  @Override
  Page<Foo> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

With the second one coming from the PagingAndSortingRepository